# How to check if all elements of type integer is within given range using lambdas and streams in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Given int[] A. Trying to make use all elements in array is greater or equals to -1000 and not greater than 1000 (incl.). How to do it properly?

**My try:**

```
boolean validIntegers = (Arrays.asList(A)).stream().allMatch(i -> (i >= -1000 && i <= 1000) );
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` accepts `T...` but `T` as generic type can represent only Objects like `int[]`, not primitive `int`. So `T...` represents `{int[]}` array, which contains internally array object, not array elements. So your stream contains array and you can't use any comparison operators on array.

To solve this problem and get stream of elements stored in array of `int`s you can use

- `IntStream.of(int...)`,
- or `Arrays.stream(yourArray)` which supports `double[]` `int[]` `long[]` and `T[]`.

So your code could be

```
boolean validIntegers = IntStream.of(A).allMatch(i -> (i >= -1000 && i <= 1000) );
```

Comment: Or just `Arrays.stream(A).allMatch(i -> (i >= -1000 && i <= 1000))`.

Comment: @Mureinik Thanks included it in answer.